# How can I use satellite assemblies in ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, satellite-assembly

I love the idea of breaking out culture-specific resources into separate assemblies, but am confused as to how this can be done for an ASP.NET application. Can someone give me a quick rundown, or perhaps point to a tutorial on the subject?

Comment: The title being longer than the body text of a question is a good indicator that more detail should be added to the body.

Comment: @Shog - have you ever seen one of those gags where someone says something very lengthy in one language and then someone else repeats it in English but it is very short? Yeah... not sure how you got all of that out of the original version. But nice work.

Answer (score 0):

[see here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/tipstricks/article.php/c11367),explanation with Example